# Connection Refused When Running SparkPi Locally

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to run a simple execution of the SparkPi example.  I started the master and one worker, then executed the job on my local "cluster", but end up getting a sequence of errors all ending with

```
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:39398
```

I originally tried running my master and worker without configuration but ended up with the same error.  I tried to change to 127.0.0.1 to test if it was maybe just a firewall issue since the server is locked down from the outside world.

My `conf/spark-conf.sh` contains the following:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1
```

Here is the order and commands I run:

1) `sbin/start-master.sh` (to start the master)

2) `bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://127.0.0.1:7077 --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 1111` (in a different session on the same machine to start the slave)

3) `bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi spark://127.0.0.1:7077` (in a different session on the same machine to start the job)

I find it hard to believe that I'm locked down enough that running locally would cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should not set SPARK_MASTER_IP to a loopback address 127.0.0.1. The worker node will not be able to connect to the MASTER node using a loopback address.

You shall set it to a valid local ip address(e.g., 192.168.0.2) in conf/spark-env.sh and add the worker's IP in conf/slaves configuration file in both MASTER and the WORKER node.

Then you can use sbin/start-all.sh to start the cluster.

And then run "bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi"