# Apache Spark EOF exception

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am getting an EOFException when running a simple job that reads a text file and collects the results. This runs fine in my dev machine but fails when executing it in standalone mode (single machine, master+worker). My setup is Apache Spark 0.9.1 Hadoop 2 prebuilt.

I'm deploying my code using the sbt-assembly plugin and generating an executable jar file.

Related stack trace:

```
14/05/27 08:22:03 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2742)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readCompressedByteArray(WritableUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readCompressedString(WritableUtils.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readCompressedStringArray(WritableUtils.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.readFields(Configuration.java:2378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readObject(ObjectWritable.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readFields(ObjectWritable.java:77)
    at org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable.readObject(SerializableWritable.scala:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcast$.read(HttpBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcast.readObject(HttpBroadcast.scala:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask$.deserializeInfo(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.readExternal(ResultTask.scala:139)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1836)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:41)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

[EDIT]

Please notice I changed the serializer and I am now using Kryo (just tried it to see whether that was the issue or not).

My spark context:

```
//Load Spark config file
lazy val conf = ConfigFactory.load

//Set Spark config object
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster(conf.getString("spark.prod.master"))  //Something like spark://host:port
      .setAppName(conf.getString("app.name"))
      .set("spark.executor.memory", conf.getString("spark.prod.config.executorMemory"))
      .set("spark.cores.max", conf.getString("spark.prod.config.coresMax"))
      .set("spark.serializer", conf.getString("spark.prod.config.serializer"))
      .set("spark.kryo.registrator", conf.getString("spark.prod.config.kryoRegistrator"))
      .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb", conf.getString("spark.prod.config.kryoSerializerBufferSize"))
      .set("spark.logConf", conf.getString("spark.prod.config.logConf"))
```

Any hints?

Comment: How did you add the `jar` file? Did you use `SparkContext.addJar`?

Comment: @visakh I set the master config property to the master's spark url (spark://whatever) and just launch the executable jar file from the master. Everything starts properly but after submitting some tasks I start receiving these errors.

Comment: @visakh The jar file contains a main class with a main method that executes all spark-related code.

Comment: I am not sure this can be answered without seeing the code that you use to read the file.

Comment: @DanielDarabos nothing special, I am just using sc.textFile method to read a local text file (I am not using hdfs) and playing with some map/filter/etc transformations.

Comment: > "I'm deploying my code using the sbt-assembly plugin and generating an executable jar file." --- would you mind sharing highlights of your sbt configuration? how did you configure `mergeStrategy` and library dependency exclusions?

Answer (score 13):

After some days struggling with it, I finally came up with a solution. I had to add the corresponding `hadoop-client` dependency to avoid this strange exception.

After that, some other already [reported errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129321/connection-refused-when-running-sparkpi-locally?rq=1) appeared. The solution to the connection refused problem was:

1. Change `sbin/start-master.sh` and/or `sbin/start-slaves.sh` and set `$SPARK_MASTER_IP` to `hostname -f` instead of `hostname`. It seems Akka only works with fully qualified names and not with hostnames or ip addresses.
2. Set also `$SPARK_MASTER_IP` in `conf/spark-env.sh` to `hostname -f` so that cluster workers can reach the master.
3. Be sure that `conf/slaves` also uses fully qualified domain names and not hostnames/ip addresses.

After these changes, everything just worked.

Hope it helps someone else!