# Intermittent Timeout Exception using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've a Spark cluster with 10 nodes, and I'm getting this exception after using the Spark Context for the first time:

```
14/11/20 11:15:13 ERROR UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:iuberdata (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Unknown exception in doAs
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1421)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    ... 4 more
```

This [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23884717/1791289) have had a similar problem but I've already tried his solution and didn't worked.

The same exception also happens [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201409.mbox/%3CCAMc-71miSp8r-p1tnxEjharnRTUhf1RBtLu2aLzyhbgA042-0A@mail.gmail.com%3E) but the problem isn't them same in here as I'm using spark version 1.1.0 in both master or slave and in client.

I've tried to increase the timeout to 120s but it still doesn't solve the problem.

I'm doploying the environment throught scripts and I'm using the context.addJar to include my code into the classpath.
This problem is intermittend, and I don't have any idea on how to track why is it happening. Anybody has faced this issue when configuring a spark cluster know how to solve it?

Comment: As this is top answer in google, for future reference, rpc timeout can occur without firewall/network configuration, if your job stalls for configured period, which is 120secs in spark 2.0. I have this problem now and searching for a solution other then increasing timeout time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firewall was missconfigured and, in some instances, it didn't allowed the slaves to connect to the cluster. 
This generated the timeout issue, as the slaves couldn't connect to the server.
If you are facing this timeout, check your firewall configs.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while since this post, but I'm facing the same problem. Could you please provide more hints how to check firewall settings that cause this issue?

Comment: Hi @OlegShirokikh, where are you deploying? Is it a local deployment? You will have to check if your cluster servers can access each other. Here the slcaves didn't have permission to access the master, and that caused this problem.

Answer (score 8):

We had a similar problem which was quite hard to debug and isolate. Long story short - Spark uses Akka which is very picky about FQDN hostnames resolving to IP addresses. Even if you specify the IP Address at all places it is not enough. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884717/apache-spark-eof-exception) helped us isolate the problem.

A useful test to run is run `netcat -l <port>` on the master and run `nc -vz <host> <port>` on the worker to test the connectivity. Run the test with an IP address and with the FQDN. You can get the name Spark is using from the WARN message from the log snippet below. For us it was `host032s4.staging.companynameremoved.info`. The IP address test for us passed and the FQDN test failed as our DNS was not setup correctly.

```
INFO 2015-07-24 10:33:45 Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@10.40.246.168:35455]
INFO 2015-07-24 10:33:45 Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@10.40.246.168:35455]
INFO 2015-07-24 10:33:45 org.apache.spark.util.Utils: Successfully started service 'driverPropsFetcher' on port 35455.
WARN 2015-07-24 10:33:45 Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@host032s4.staging.companynameremoved.info:50855]. Address is now gated for 60000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters.
ERROR 2015-07-24 10:34:15 org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:skumar cause:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
```

Another thing which we had to do was to specify the `spark.driver.host` and `spark.driver.port` properties in the spark submit script. This was because we had machines with two IP addresses and the FQDN resolved to the wrong IP address.

**Make sure your network and DNS entries are correct!!**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I managed to get around it by using `cluster` deploy mode when [submitting the application to Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html).

(Because even allowing all the incoming traffic to both my master and the single slave didn't allow me to use the `client` deploy mode. Before changing them I had default security group (AWS firewall) settings set up by [Spark EC2 scripts](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/ec2-scripts.html) from Spark 1.2.0).