# How can I run Spark job programmatically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wan't to run Spark job programmatically - submit `SparkPi` calculation to remote cluster directly from Idea (my laptop):

```
object SparkPi {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
      .setMaster("spark://host-name:7077")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val n = 100000 * slices
    val count = spark.parallelize(1 to n, slices).map { i =>
      val x = random * 2 - 1
      val y = random * 2 - 1
      if (x * x + y * y < 1) 1 else 0
    }.reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
    spark.stop()
  }

}
```

However, when I run it, I observe the following error:

```
14/12/08 11:31:20 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:remeniuk (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Unknown exception in doAs
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1421)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    ... 4 more
```

When I run the same script with `spark-submit` from my laptop, I see the same error.

And only when I upload the jar to remote cluster (machine, where master is running), job complete successfully:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://host-name:7077 --class com.viaden.crm.spark.experiments.SparkPi ../spark-experiments_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception stack, it should be your local firewall issue.

please refer to this similar case
[Intermittent Timeout Exception using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039954/intermittent-timeout-exception-using-spark)