# Using spark cluster remotely

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use a spark cluster remotely, so basically I have a 3 nodes, 1 master and 2 workers 'far' from my laptop, but I want to use them to make computation.
I can connect easily to the driver typing:
./spark-shell --master spark://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077

And I see my application on spark web interface on the driver, but actions are not executed, I think because workers which should connect to me have networks problems.
So I set on spark-env.sh my public IP:
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=XX.XX.15.215

but doing that I get:

```
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
```

16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/02/11 16:34:04 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.

Comment: What do you see on your spark master web UI? Is it waiting for resources? Do you see the workers connected to the master? Can you post a screenshot of the master web UI?

Comment: The warning you have posted should not cause a problem for you as it will attempt to bind to the next port.

Comment: Saket as you can see it stops trying at  some point

Answer (score 0):

It is quite important for the DNS entries to be correct and for the workers and the master to be able to connect to the driver. If they are not directly reachable using the hostname, you can specify the `spark.driver.host` and `spark.driver.port` as part of the spark submit command.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31608975/1229509) for a similar problem I had.

Comment: Do you think is not possible to solve using spark-shell?

Comment: You can specify these in `spark-env.sh`.

Comment: lie this:
SPARK_DRIVER_PORT=10002      ?

Comment: Sorry, you have to use conf/spark-defaults.conf as specified at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#loading-configuration-from-a-file and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: So I need to set those values those values in the workers and in the master not in my PC ?

Comment: I think it should be sufficient to set it on the driver. However you will have to test it out to be sure.

Comment: I passed those parameters to submit but it still does not work..
It is not able to bind

Comment: Do you have permissions to bind a port?

Comment: above 1024 yes, but it looks like I cannot bind on public IP

Comment: it looks like workers are still using private IP:
16/02/11 18:50:37 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]

16/02/11 18:50:41 ERROR UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:edge7 (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.1.4.225:10001
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.1.4.225:10001

Comment: I had a very similar error on my machine and the problem was that my DNS was not setup correct for the host I was running the spark job on.