# Apache Spark Running Locally Giving Refused Connection Error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have Spark and Hadoop installed on OS X. I successfully worked through an example where Hadoop ran locally, had files stored in HDFS and I ran spark with

```sh
spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

and from within the shell worked with HDFS. I'm having problems, however, trying to get Spark to run without HDFS, just locally on my machine. I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129321/connection-refused-when-running-sparkpi-locally) but it doesn't feel right messing around with environment variables when the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html) says

> It’s easy to run locally on one machine — all you need is to have java
>   installed on your system PATH, or the JAVA_HOME environment variable
>   pointing to a Java installation.

If I run the basic `SparkPi` example I get the correct output.

If I try run the sample Java app [they provide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#tab_java_3), again, I get output, but this time with **connection refused** errors relating to **port 9000**, which sounds like it's trying to connect to **Hadoop**, but I don't know why because I'm not specifying that

```sh
    $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local[4] ~/study/scala/sampleJavaApp/target/simple-project-1.0.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From 37-2-37-10.tssg.org/10.37.2.37 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
...
...
...
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:699)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access(Client.java:367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
        ... 51 more
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
...
...
...
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.37.2.37:4040
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO util.Utils: path = /private/var/folders/cg/vkq1ghks37lbflpdg0grq7f80000gn/T/spark-c6ba18f5-17a5-4da9-864c-509ec855cadf/blockmgr-b66cc31e-7371-472f-9886-4cd33d5ba4b1, already present as root for deletion.
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO util.Utils: Shutdown hook called
    15/07/31 11:05:06 INFO util.Utils: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/cg/vkq1ghks37lbflpdg0grq7f80000gn/T/spark-c6ba18f5-17a5-4da9-864c-509ec855cadf
```

Any pointers/explanations as to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated!

---

## UPDATE

It seems that the fact I have the environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` set is causing some issues. Under that directory, I have `core-site.xml` which contains the following

```xml
<property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>                                     
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>                             
</property>
```

If I change the value e.g. `<value>hdfs://localhost:9100</value>` then when I attempt to run the spark job, the connection refused error refers to this changed port

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From 37-2-37-10.tssg.org/10.37.2.37 to localhost:9100 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

So for some reason, despite instructing it to run locally, it is trying to connect to HDFS. If I remove the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable, the job works fine.

Comment: are you setting up the master configuration inside your job as well?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean (which could be a sign of why it's not working!). I am just running the command `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local[4] ~/study/scala/sampleJavaApp/target/simple-project-1.0.jar`

Comment: how are you setting up your SparkContext in your Java project?

Comment: I'm using the exact official Spark Java example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#tab_java_3)

Comment: where is your core-site.xml

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apache Spark uses the Hadoop client libraries for file access when you use `sc.textFile`. This makes it possible to use an `hdfs://` or `s3n://` path for example. You can also use local paths as `file:/home/robocode/foo.txt`.

If you specify a file name without a schema, `fs.default.name` is used. It defaults to `file:`, but you explicitly override it to `hdfs://localhost:9000` in your `core-site.xml`. So if you don't specify the schema, it's trying to read from HDFS.

The simplest solution is to specify the schema:

```
JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile("file:/home/robocode/foo.txt").cache();
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, HADOOP_CONF_DIR was defined, so I just unset the environment variable.

```
unset HADOOP_CONF_DIR
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the environment variables that you have defined before for the Hadoop related example are still interfering with your test.

Given that you are using the official Spark Java example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();
...
}
```

I would suggest to explictly set the Master, as default values are taken otherwise.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Simple Application")
```

Check the [SparkConf doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.SparkConf) for more information:

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but even with master explicitly set it is still attempting to communicate with HDFS as a result of `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` being set. I know I could just unset and set the env variable as required but there must be a more sensible way